# How to toggle dropdown menu for each row in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> JSP code
>
> I have been trying to toggle the dropdown menu, but it is not working, I used Datatables js to do the ordering of the list. Because of that Datatables js the toggle is not working. Is there any script to toggle the menu for each row?

```
<table width="80%" id="studentdetailslist" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Register Number</th>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Sports Played</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Date added</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <%
        for (Studentdetails details : studentdetailslist) {
            %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= details.getRegisterNumber() %></td>
                    <td><%= details.getName() %></td>
                    <td><%= details.getAge() %></td>
                    <td><%= details.getGender() %></td>
                    <td><%= details.getSports() %></td>
                    <td><%= details.getStandard() %></td>
                    <td><fmt:formatDate value="<%= details.getCreateDate() %>" pattern="dd/MMM/yyyy"/></td>
                    <td><div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropwdown">Actions
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">View</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <%
        }   
    %>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#studentdetailslist').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            targets: [ 0 ],
            orderData: [ 0, 1 ]
        }, {
            targets: [ 1 ],
            orderData: [ 1, 0 ]
        }, {
            targets: [ 4 ],
            orderData: [ 4, 0 ]
        } ]
    } );
} );

</script>
```

Comment: How do you toggle drop down menu in JS?

Comment: simple toggle is not working for each row.

Comment: FYI, it is more understandable if you post the `output HTML` instead of core code. So that we can reproduce the problem. 

This site has a great tool for inserting code, JS, html, and css together. And you can also include external resources such as jquery, datatables etc...

Answer (score 1):

On your button your have data-toggle="dropwdown" change it to data-toggle="dropdown" and it will work!